# Way to access const from another component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my first time to develop a react application.

I am encountering difficulties in retrieving const data from another component.

Here is the const I want to access to the other component.

```
TableComponent.js

export default function({ infinite }) {
const [checkedMap, setCheckedMap] = useState(new Map());

const viewDetails = () => {
    return (
      "url here" +
      Array.from(checkedMap.keys()).join() +
      "/details"
    );
  };
}

//other codes
```

Is there a way how to access viewDetails to a different component?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you `export` the `const`:

```
export const viewDetails = () => {
    return (
      "url here" +
      Array.from(checkedMap.keys()).join() +
      "/details"
    );
  };
}
```

This must be in the module scope (on the same level as the default export):

```
export const viewDetails = () => {}
export default function({ infinite }) {}
```

You can then import from the other component:

```
import { viewDetails } from './TableComponent';
```

If you want to import *both* the default export and the named export:

```
import TableComponent, { viewDetails } from './TableComponent';
```

Finally, you can also access the named import from the default import:

```
import TableComponent from './TableComponent';
TableComponent.viewDetails();
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I cannot separate the viewDetails from the function because it has dependencies on checkedMap, which is declared and used inside the function.

Comment: By exporting this function, are you intending for the function to be called by something else?  Are you trying to close-over checkedMap?

Comment: I wanted to pass the checkedMap value or viewDetails function to other component so that it can change the url for api get call

Answer (score 1):

you have to return your const viewDetails...either you need to self invoking function or return the function...e.g.

```
export default function({ infinite }) {
const viewDetails = () => {
    return (
      "url here" +
      Array.from(checkedMap.keys()).join() +
      "/details"
    );
  };
return viewDetails;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//TableComponent.js

export const viewDetails = () => {
  return (
    "url here" +
    Array.from(checkedMap.keys()).join() +
    "/details"
  );
};
```

And in another file you can access this const as below

```
import { viewDetails } from './TableComponent';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const viewDetails = () => {
  return (
    "url here" +
    Array.from(checkedMap.keys()).join() +
    "/details"
  );
};

export default viewDetails;
```