# How to access data from other components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import LoginGuestButton, {getGuestValue} from './components/LoginGuestButton';

function App() {
  return (
    //If User is not a guest user, then display the login page
    (!getGuestValue) && (
    <LoginGuestButton/>
    )
  );
}

export default App;
```

LoginGuestButton.js

```
import React from 'react';

var guestValue = false;

const LoginGuestButton = () => {
    function switchGuestValue() {
        guestValue = true;
    }

    return (
        <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" onClick = {switchGuestValue}>
        Sign in as Demo User
        </button>
      )

}

export const getGuestValue = () => {        
    return (
      guestValue
    );
}
export default LoginGuestButton
```

This is my first React app and I am building a simple Login screen. When the user clicks on the "Sign in as Guest button", I want to clear the screen and begin presenting sample data to the user. In order to do so, I need to grab a "signed in" boolean that should be set to true after the "sign in as guest button" has been pressed.

The code I have presented is not working. For some reason, getGuestValue is not known to app.js.
The code above presents no error messages. I followed the details given in this question:

> [Way to access const from another component in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289828/way-to-access-const-from-another-component-in-react)

but it is not working for me.

Somebody please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome, please read the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html). You will make your life so much easier if you read it start to finish. As this is your first React app only read the Main Concepts section and the Hooks section. After you have created a couple of apps go back and read the Advanced Guides section.

I cannot answer your question without having to explain how props and the basics of React work which is way beyond the scope of Stackoverflow's question and answer format. If you read the docs and still cannot work out an answer to your question comment on this answer and I will help you.

Comment: Thank you! I read through the documentation and was able to find a solution to my problem.

Comment: You should mark an answer as accepted so people know that you are no longer looking for an answer